# About how much damage does Ashe's ultimate robot, Bob, deal?

Tags: overwatch

I am one of those Overwatch players that likes to learn all of the numbers, so I'd like to know the numbers to see how many players a well-placed Bob could kill at once based on said numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Overwatch Wiki](https://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Ashe):

> Charge: 120
>   Arm Cannon: 112 per second, 14 per bullet, 1092 overall

Comment: Next question: How long can Bastion tank him in Sentry while self-healing? :)

Comment: @OXiGEN That would probably be best asked as a new question.